# web server for single page application

Tags: apache, nginx

I need a web server for single page application. Basically I need to things from it:

- serve static from /blah-blah/app/assets
- response with /blah-blah/app/index.html to any other request

Apache or nginx seems very complicated for this (I'm total n00b with them).

Is there a really simple solution for VPS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Cloud Storage

   https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration
2. Amazon Simple Storage Service

   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html
3. Google Drive

   https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: what about VPS? I alraeady have a server

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way to host a static site than Nginx or Apache with VPS since they are both packaged software. You need only 3 steps installation=>configuration=>service start.